# How to obtain values of request variables using Python and Flask

Tags: python, variables, request, flask

I'm wondering how to go about obtaining the value of a POST/GET request variable using Python with Flask.

With Ruby, I'd do something like this:

```
variable_name = params["FormFieldValue"]
```

How would I do this with Flask?

Comment: Have you considered looking at the Flask documentation? It's covered in the [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#accessing-request-data). Hint: `request.form["fieldname"]`

Comment: Have you read this - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/ ? If not, I would recommend to run through it, because it will explain a lot of the things which are not clear in the beginning. Have fun with Flask ;)

Comment: You can also do `request.args["myvar"]` to access GET key-values

Comment: RTFM comments are my absolute favourite comments :Kappa:

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can get posted form data from `request.form` and query string data from `request.args`.

```
myvar =  request.form["myvar"]
```

```
myvar = request.args["myvar"]
```

Answer (score 186):

If you want to retrieve POST data:

```
first_name = request.form.get("firstname")
```

If you want to retrieve GET (query string) data:

```
first_name = request.args.get("firstname")
```

Or if you don't care/know whether the value is in the query string or in the post data:

```
first_name = request.values.get("firstname")
```

**request.values** is a **CombinedMultiDict** that combines Dicts from **request.form** and **request.args**.

Answer (score 4):

Adding more to Jason's more generalized way of retrieving the POST data or GET data

```
from flask_restful import reqparse

def parse_arg_from_requests(arg, **kwargs):
    parse = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parse.add_argument(arg, **kwargs)
    args = parse.parse_args()
    return args[arg]

form_field_value = parse_arg_from_requests('FormFieldValue')
```