# Obtaining boolean value from file upload in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm using flask to store audio files.  When sending the post request to store the file, I'd also like to send additional information about the file, specifically a boolean value.

Currently I'm accessing the file with flask by doing:

```
file = request.files['file']
```

I'm sending the file to the flask server in swift by doing:

```
request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(param, filePathKey: "file", path: params["url"] as? NSURL, boundary: boundary)
```

Is there a way I can obtain the boolean value with the file upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A form when submitted can have more than one value specified by the name attribute on the html element inside that form.

```
<form>
   <input type="text" value="true" name="isFileUploaded">
   <input type="file" name="myFile">
</form>
```

To get the parameters sent to the server, you can always use

**POST**

```
request.form.get('<your_name_used_in_the_form'>) #in this case its isFileUploaded
```

**GET**

```
request.args.get('<your_name_used_in_the_form>')
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279399/how-to-obtain-values-of-request-variables-using-python-and-flask) answer for more...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I see that I can easily access the file by doing `file = request.files['file']`.  Can I access the contents within `param` just as easily?  In the past, I would handle a regular post request by doing `data = MultiDict(mapping=request.json)`, but that won't work in this case.

Comment: Just try it out via request.form.get('param_name') , it should work as its a normal that is being submitted to you. In ideal scenario this should work.

Comment: i'm not using a form so I don't think `request.form.get('param_name')` will work.  Thats why I've been using `data = MultiDict(mapping=request.json)`.  When I type `request`, `request.form` isn't an option.