# How to print/Display my search results on the same webpage using Flask and HTML?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a dataset of Players and the number of goals they have scored, this dataset is stored in a dataframe. I want to display or print the stats and player details that I have searched for on the search bar, but I am always getting a bad request error

This is the dataset [Dataset Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bhyl.jpg)

this is how the Webpage looks like [Webpage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WIj8.jpg)

MainProject Python file

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import DataFrame
    from fuzzywuzzy import process



    scorers=pd.read_csv('tests.csv')

    def main(searchplayer):
        scorers=pd.read_csv('tests.csv')
        player=list(scorers['Player'])
        goals=list(scorers['Goals'])
        team=list(scorers['Team'])


        df_data={'player': player,
                'goals': goals,
                'team': team}

        df_main=pd.DataFrame(df_data, columns=['player', 'goals', 'team'])
        def getSearchedProducts(searchplayer, choices, limit=30):
            res=process.extract(searchplayer, choices, limit=limit)
            return res

        searchplayer=str(searchplayer)
        result=getSearchedProducts(searchplayer, player)

        player_result_list = [res[0] for res in result if res[1]>=70]

        player_result_df = df_main[df_main['Product'].isin(product_result_list)]

        player_result_df.index+=1
        list_player_res=[(tabulate(player_result_df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))]

        return list_player_res
```

Flask File

```
    import os
    from flask import Flask, flash, request, render_template, 
            redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
    from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
    from MainProject import main
    from flask_cors import CORS

    searchplayer=""

    app=Flask(__name__)

    app.config['CACHE_TYPE']='null'
    CORS(app)

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def homepage():
        searchplayer=request.form['prod']
        list_player_res = main(searchplayer)
        return render_template('home.html', list_player_res=list_player_res)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

A code snippet of my Html file

```
    <form class="form-inline" method="POST">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="prod" type="search" placeholder="Search for Players" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-light my-sm-0" type="Submit">Search</button>  
          </form>
```

This is what I tried:

```
    @app.route('/')

    def homepage():
           return render_template('home.html')


    @app.route('/searchpg', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def searchpg():
        global searchplayer
        if request.method == 'POST':
            searchplayer = request.form.get['prod']
            list_res, list_prod_res = main(searchplayer)
            print(list_player_res)

            return render_template('home.html', list_player_res=list_player_res)
```

HTML This is what I did:

```
          <form class="form-inline" method="POST">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="prod" 
    type="search" placeholder="Search for Players" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-light my-sm-0" 
       type="Submit">Search</button>  
                  </form>  
                </div>
              </nav>

            <br> 
            {% for result in list_player_res %} 
                    {{result}}
                 {% endfor %}   
            </br>
```

How do I search for players in that searchbar and the results get displayed on the same screen?

Comment: Your route doesn't differentiate between GET and POST requests. You need to shield the part that expects form input within an `if request.method == 'POST':` guard, otherwise you get an error when you initially try load the page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling GET and POST in same Flask view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018603/handling-get-and-post-in-same-flask-view)

Comment: No, it doesn't. It doesnt print/display the output though

Comment: Well, come on now, you need to give me something to work on here. It almost certainly _is_ your issue, but I can't see how you've attempted to implement it or what the issue is

Comment: I can't read that. Please [edit] the question

Comment: Sorry...Yeah!
whatever I have done its added in the question.

Comment: No idea how to add the code in the comments